# Writing a recurrence relation for a sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

I'm learning about recurrence relations at the moment. I can solve them and figure out the bounds on them, but what I'm not really sure of is how to come up with a recurrence relation for a particular algorithm. Here's an example in my book:

```
// Sort array A[] between indices p and r inclusive.

SampleSort (A, p, r) {

     // Base Case: use HeapSort
     //
     if (r - p < 12) {
        HeapSort(A, p, r) ;
     }


     //  Break the array into 1st quarter, 2nd quarter and second half
     //
     n = r - p + 1 ;        // number of items in A[p..r] inclusive
     q1 = p - 1 + n/4 ;     // end of 1st quarter
     q2 = q1 + n/4 ;        // end of 2nd quarter


     //  Sort each of the 3 pieces
     //  using SampleSort recursively, Insertion-Sort and Heap-Sort
     //
     SampleSort (A, p, q1) ;
     InsertionSort (A, q1 + 1, q2) ;
     HeapSort (A, q2 + 1, r) ;


     // Merge the 3 sorted arrays into 1 sorted array
     //
     Merge (A, p, q1, q2) ;     // Merge 1st & 2nd quarter
     Merge (A, p, q2, r) ;      // Merge 1st & 2nd halves

     return  ;
}
```

It also says I can assume InsertionSort, HeapSort and Merge are Θ(n2), Θ(n log n) and Θ(n).
Here's what I've come up with so far:
I'm dividing the array into three pieces. The first two pieces are 1/4 of the original data, the and the third piece (the half) is 1/2 of the data. 
So right now I have T(n) = 2T(n/4) + T(n/2).
Not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Only one of those three sorts is a recursive call. Once you have the proper recurrence, apply the Master Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

As David points out in his comment, there is only one *recursive* call in the algorithm. So your recurrence relation looks like this:

```
      SampleSort   InsertionSort        HeapSort         Merges
          |             |                  |               |
          v             v                  v               v
T(n) = T(n / 4) + O((n / 4)^2) + O((n / 2) log (n / 2)) + O(n)
     = T(n / 4) + O(n^2)
```

Using the [Master theorem (Case 3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_3), we conclude that

```
T(n) = O(n^2)     (worst case)
```

Because `SampleSort` on `n` items involves `HeapSort` on `n / 2` items, which has best case `Ω((n / 2) log (n / 2)) = Ω(n log n)`, we know that

```
T(n) = Ω(n log n)  (best case)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding guys! I was having trouble understanding why SampleSort was was the recursive call...then I felt really dumb after realizing why. Makes a lot more sense though, thank you both.